# Customer order email not sent with SMTP PRO

Tags: email, magento

I have installed smtp pro from mangento connect manager,configured for my general settings for custom smtp.

When I go to my sales > order and send order email, I get message "email sent", though I don't receive any email.

while I run the test I get the error message:

> "Exception message was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender."

Is this message from the mail server? Or have I done something wrong with extension setup itself?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your system log and exception log. there you will get some hint to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's coming back from your SMTP server - looks like it's restricting the
"from:" header values.

You would need to configure `"Send As"` permission on your mail server to allow your agent accounts to send email as your outbound mailbox account.
Below are instructions on how to do it in some of the more common email server/providers.

**Exchange 2007 &2010**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676368%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx

**Office365:**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2572646

**Google Apps:**

https://sites.google.com/a/apu.edu/gmail-for-apu/executive-assistants/send-on-behalf